# make append and separate by white space

Tags: make

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/postgrespro/rum/master/Makefile
https://github.com/postgrespro/rum
I'm trying to understand this behavior of `make`.

```
INCLUDES = rum.h rumsort.h
RELATIVE_INCLUDES = $(addprefix src/, $(INCLUDES))
$(info $(RELATIVE_INCLUDES))
```

returns:

```
src/rum.h src/rumsort.h
make: *** No targets.  Stop.
```

Not sure why it appended and also separated by one white space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`addprefix` [treats its arguments as a series of names](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/File-Name-Functions.html#index-addprefix):

> The value of *prefix* is prepended to the front of each individual name and the resulting larger names are concatenated with single spaces between them.

In your case, `addprefix` prepends `src/` to `rum.h` and `rumsort.h` (separately), concatenates the result with single spaces, and returns the result, `src/rum.h src/rumsort.h`.